# Android Facebook SDK: "An error occured with holyplanets connect. Please try again later." How do I fix it?

Tags: android, facebook, connection

I have integrated Facebook into my Android application. It was worked fine before last week. Since a couple of days ago (before it was working fine) I now sometimes get an error when posting to wall page saying `An error occured with holyplanets connect. Please try again later.`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you share some more info such as the url/fb-api that you are using and the reply you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Facebook Dev Forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=317738#p317738)... seems to have solved for some people.

Comment: i have resolved this problem with the latest android sdk. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up disabling facebook SSO (single sign-on), and it works correctly now. The problem was caused by the latest updates to the Facebook app.